# kafka streams not fetching all records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a java Kafka streams application that reads from a topic do some filtering and transformations and writing the data back to Kafka to a different topic.
I print the stream object on every step.
I noticed that if I send more than dozens of records to the input topic, some records are **not** consumed by my Kafka streams application.

when using kafka-console-consumer.sh to consume from the input topic, I do receive all records.

I'm running Kafka 1.0.0 with one broker and one partition topic.

Any idea why?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String bootstrapServers = System.getenv("KAFKA");
  final String inputTopic = System.getenv("INPUT_TOPIC");
  final String outputTopic = System.getenv("OUTPUT_TOPIC");
  final String gatewayTopic = System.getenv("GATEWAY_TOPIC");
  final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
  streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "PreProcess");
  streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "PreProcess-client");
  streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
  streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
  streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
  streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
  streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 300L);


  final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
  final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream(inputTopic);
  textLines.print();
  StreamsTransformation streamsTransformation = new StreamsTransformation(builder);
  KTable<String,Gateway> gatewayKTable = builder.table(gatewayTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), SerdesUtils.getGatewaySerde()));
  KStream<String, Message> gatewayIdMessageKStream = streamsTransformation.getStringMessageKStream(textLines,gatewayKTable);
  gatewayIdMessageKStream.print();
  KStream<String, FlatSensor> keyFlatSensorKStream = streamsTransformation.transformToKeyFlatSensorKStream(gatewayIdMessageKStream);
  keyFlatSensorKStream.to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), SerdesUtils.getFlatSensorSerde()));
  keyFlatSensorKStream.print();

  KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
  streams.cleanUp();
  streams.start();
  // Add shutdown hook to respond to SIGTERM and gracefully close Kafka Streams
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    streams.close();
  }));

}
```

Comment: This can happen because of mismatched offset. Check for offset maintainance in kafka consumer.

Comment: Please provide the code for your topology and your logging output.

Comment: You might need to reset your applications before restart: https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/